# No route matches [GET] "/pages/about%22"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie with Rails and making a simple Rails program and when I make a route path like this

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
    <li><a href=<%= pages_about_path %>">About</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Location", pages_location_path %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
    <li><a href=<%= pages_about_path %>">About</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Location", pages_location_path %></li>
```

It shows me that, I had an error `No route matches [GET] "/pages/about%22"` when I click on the button `About`. Another button were ok.

I thought that I must make a link and add it into `pages_about_path`, am I right ? I am very confuse, could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You are missing the opening double quote for the href

Comment: Thank you for your comment! You are right, that is my missing!